# How to correctly merge dict with anchor in YAML

Tags: yaml

Please help merge dict with anchor in YAML to files, I try to do this but YAML return wrong result. Thanks for help

```yaml
common_files: &common_files
    - file_path: "link -1"
      content_pattern:
      - "text"
      - "text"
      one: "zoo"
      two: "foo"
      three: "fii" 
    - file_path: "link -2"
      content_pattern:
      - "text"
      - "text"
      one: "zoo"
      two: "foo"
      three: "fii" 

files: 
    - <<: *common_files
    - file_path: "link-3"
      content_pattern:
      - "text"
      - "text"
      one: "zoo"
      two: "foo"
      three: "fii"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` works on mappings, but you try to make it work on sequences. This is not possible. You can include the common files individually via alias, eg:

```yaml
common_files:
    - &link1
      file_path: "link -1"
      content_pattern:
      - "text"
      - "text"
      one: "zoo"
      two: "foo"
      three: "fii" 
    - &link2
      file_path: "link -2"
      content_pattern:
      - "text"
      - "text"
      one: "zoo"
      two: "foo"
      three: "fii" 

files: 
    - *link1
    - *link2
    - file_path: "link-3"
      content_pattern:
      - "text"
      - "text"
      one: "zoo"
      two: "foo"
      three: "fii"
```

Merge is a non-standard YAML feature. There is no similar feature for sequences. No implementation I know of provides what you'd need to prepend all *common_files* to *files* with one command.